# Rails Route adding dot with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, path, routes

My rails app is adding a dot/period "." into the route when trying to browse to a devise gem user's profile.

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

(Basically using routes to allow for some custom functions -  it should be still using the default devise routing paths.

Rake routes output:

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
```

Link in view:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_registration_path(user) %>
```

Where user is defined in a `.each` loop.

Outputted Link in URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/edit.2
```

My goal is to have a link to edit any user's profile (permissions controlled outside these items of course).

I "think" my problem is the routes.rb and not specifying the path correctly there. I think it should be something that would have a `rake routes` that includes an `:id` parameter.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal routes's devise, `registrations#edit` is for edit current signed-in user, If you want to CRUD interface for users (I think you want to editing a user), you can add another controller (e.g `users_controller.rb`) and make some action , example for controller :

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   if params[:user][:password].blank?
     params[:user].delete(:password)
     params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
   end
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to some_path, notice: 'Updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { 
          flash[:alert] = "Something wrong"
          render :action => :edituser
        }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

On your `routes.rb` you can following like this

```
scope '/user' do
 match '/edit/:id' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
 put '/update/:id' => 'users#update', :as => :update_user
end
```

And links on each section looks like :

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>
```

references :

- [How To: Manage users through a CRUD interface](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)
- [CRUD Devise Example](https://gist.github.com/vjm/1056194)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking to do. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

I think Devise's `edit_user_registration_path` uses `current_user` internally, so you shouldn't need the `(user)` in your `link_to`